# Ending pythonw.exe process on manual exit

Tags: python

I can't seem to find the right google search to figure out something that should be easy.

I am using wxPython to create a GUI, and saving the Python files as .pyw so I don't have a console. Then I am importing another .py file into the main window when a user does an action. Doing so created the pythonw.exe instance that won't close. To be clear, the .pyw that opens if I only open the main console will clear from my processes if I don't open/insert the other .py file from the first file while running.

When I use the program everything is perfectly fine, but when I use the Windows "X" button to close I still get pythonw.exe in my processes, and the file I am printing errors to is locked due to something else using it(the pythonw.exe). What code do I need to use to make sure that python is exiting completely? It also seems to stay whenever I build in a file - exit as well, and it is only staying on the processes if I insert the other module(only done with user input)

Also this may be obvious but if I open the imported file manually it has the same behavior, as in the python.exe closes when I close out of the file.

Comment: did you override default close operation method? you core(functionality) and gui(main process) are the same processes?

Comment: No overrides. The imported file is .py and opens up python.exe when opened separately. The main file is .pyw and opens pythonw.exe. pythonw.exe process ends if I don't do the import of the .py file. It doesn't end if I import the .py and then close both.

Comment: so the problem is in the imported file. Probably it has threads running. Post the code of the imported file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the application you can do this like this:

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```

This works when the normal exit() or reaching the end of the main file does not work becaus of background threads running.

But so you are ending killing all running threads. You should look into the code of the imported file which causes the problem to see if it has threads.